# Can I change my username on theRPF?

Tags: username

Does anyone know if there's any way to change your username on [theRPF.com](http://www.therpf.com)? I first signed in with Facebook, which auto-created a user for me, based off my Facebook identity, but I really would prefer my username on RPF be a different handle.

I've tried emailing/tweeting/facebooking the RPF, but I got no response, not even an automated one.

Any help would be appreciated. I'm hoping I don't have to delete my account and recreate to do this, because I've already made a couple posts on RPF.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, we don't change user names. However, due to Facebook Connect automatically populating your user name and not giving you an option, we will be glad to change your name. Looking through our records, I don't see any correspondence from you, but if you will email me at admin@moviepropsites.com, I will get you squared away.

Art Andrews
Movie Prop Sites, LLC
(therpf.com)

Comment: Awesome; thanks! I will be in touch shortly.